# Android sdk won't install windows 7 32 bit

Tags: android, cordova, sdk

I have a Dell Windows 7 32 bit Intel Pentium 4 Optiplex GX280, and another HP Windows Vista 64 bit AMD Phenom 9150 Pavilion a6007. I wanted my app published in the Google Play Store with Apache Cordova, so I needed the Android SDK. I installed it on the Optiplex, but when I went to open it, the folder was empty and the app didn't exist. So I went on the Pavilion and it worked fine. The only problem was, I needed Intel VT-x, and the Pavilion has an AMD processor. Am I doing something wrong? Is the SDK not supported on my Optiplex? Oh, and I forgot to mention, the Optiplex was upgraded to 7, because it was running XP.

Answer (score 0):

3.4 GHz p4 with 512 mb ram optiplex launched 2005 .
Here the processor seems outdated compared to i7,i5 but 512 mb ram seems way less than optimum requirements . but folder should not get deleted ,you should try copying it again